# JavaScript blockscope with let

Tags: javascript, var, let

I modified the original script from the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) given below.

1. What is the type of var? Is the type assigned only after a value is assigned to a variable.
2. Does `var b = 1` overwrite the previous statement `var b = 10`? Or just the variable b?
3. Is let a non-standard language feature? I read [here](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations) that it is supported in ECMAScript 6.

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

if (a === 5) {
  let a = 4; // The scope is inside the if-block
  var b = 1; // The scope is inside the function

  alert(a);  // 4
  alert(b);  // 1
} 

alert(a); // 5
alert(b); // 1
```

Comment: ECMAScript 6 is an upcoming standard, it just doesn't have wide support yet and it's not complete so it's still subject to change.

Comment: Variables don't have types. Values do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the type of var?

`var` has no type. It's a [keyword](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.1) used to declare variables.

> Is the type assigned only after a value is assigned to a variable?

When you declare a variable but don't assign any value to it, its value will be [undefined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9), whose type is [Undefined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.10).

> Does var b = 1 overwrite the previous statement var b = 10? Or just the variable b?

Variable statements are hoisted to the top. That means that those are equivalent:

```js
// ...
var b = 10;
if(cond) var b = 1;
```

```js
var b;
// ...
b = 10;
if(cond) b = 1;
```

So, since `b` was already declared, `var b = 1` will be equivalent to `b = 1`.

> Is let a non-standard language feature? I read here that it is supported in ECMAScript 6.

`let` was introduced in [JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7), and was not part of any ECMA-262 standard at the time.

Now ECMAScript 6 has standardized it (in a bit different way than JS 1.7). However, be aware that ECMAScript 6 is still a draft.

Comment: According to the MDN, let is being deprecated and being removed in the future. I would advise against using it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Only [non-standard let extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Non-standard_let_extensions) ([let block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let_block) and [let expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#let_expressions)) will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, `var x` has no type. `var x = 1` has a type of `number`.
2. `var b` doesn't overwrite the other statement, it just sets a new variable for the given scope. It means within that scope you get the newly assigned value for b.
3. `let` is es6. So yes and no, depending on where your code is running.